# Is there a faster way to remove and store an element from an unordered set

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, stl

I have an unordered set like below:

```
[1,2,3,4,6,7,5]
```

I want to remove and store an element from my unordered set and I don't care which element is removed.

I am currently doing the following. Is there a faster way to do it?

```
auto it = set_of_ints.begin();
set_of_ints.erase(it);
.....
.....
std::cout << "removed element is: " << *it << std::endl;
```

I meant to paste the print statement before the erase but many answers discuss that issue. So I am leaving it as is.

Comment: The code above is UB at the point of dereferencing the iterator `it`.

Comment: @RichardHodges I accidentally rearranged the lines. I meant to use the dereferenced value before the erase

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the `std::unordered_set::erase` member function is the only function meant to be used when erasing elements from the set, and the [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/erase) say:

> **Complexity**
>   Given an instance c of unordered_set:
>   1) Average case: constant, worst case: c.size()
>   [...]

So why is it `c.size()` in the worst case?  Note that `erase` has a return value:

> **Return value**
>   1-2) Iterator following the last removed element.
>   [...]

The function has to find the "next element". `std::unordered_set` stores its data in so called bucket lists. Ideally, this is the next available slot in the same bucket list as the one which accommodates the element which you erase. Worst case, it is the last available slot in some other bucket (and hence it scales with the size of the container). This depends on the insert/erase history of the container. You can have a look at the `libcxx` implementation [here](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/d17f6ab61b2492cdf5c1c88c36915456206f84fe/libcxx/include/__hash_table#L2660), there is a loop traversing the nodes in the bucket list (the mechanism is well explained by [@eeroika's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54438659/9593596)).

---

Besides, not that (also from the docs on `erase`):

> References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated

So dereferencing the iterator `it` after you erased it from the set is undefined behavior. You can fix it by

```
auto it = set_of_ints.begin();
const int value = *it;

set_ot_ints.erase(it);

std::cout << "removed element is: " << value << "\n";
```

Comment: I'd enclose the first three lines in a scope to ensure `it` is not used after it has been invalidated and making that fact more obvious.

Comment: @YSC Good point, but then `value` would need to be non-`const`, is that worth it?

Comment: scope might be a lambda returning the value :-)

Comment: Ho that's true. Just leave it like this, don't bring IILE into the mix. That's beyond the point of your answer.

Comment: BTW, the answer doesn't answer the choice of element to remove.

Comment: Well... It never hurts to improve the maintainability of a code with the definition of: `template<class Container> auto pop(Container const& c) { auto const result = *begin(c) ; c.erase(begin(c)) ; return result; }`

Comment: @YSC I know that this is not directly related to the question I had asked but how much more expensive is this pop operation when compared to popping the last element of a vector? `auto val = a.back();
a.pop_back();`  where a is an `std::vector` of ints.

Comment: @Morpheus This is another question you should ask, we'd be happy to answer. But succintly, the `std::unordered_set` is _smarter_ than a `std::vector`. This smartness comes with a cost `std::vector` doesn't have to pay. Erasing the last element of a vector is almost free (not counting the destruction of the element itself and the decrement of the size counter).

Comment: @YSC. Thanks for the answer. I figured that would be the case but for some reason hoped that this implementation is not very expensive.

Comment: worst-case average complexity is an oxymoron :)

Comment: @eerorika Thanks, fixed :)

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no faster way to remove an element of a set than `erase`. Unless your intention is to transfer the element into another set in which case `extract` may be faster as a whole.

The choice of element is irrelevant; except if you don't have an iterator at hand, the fastest iterator to get is `begin`.

---

In case you're wondering the case where erasure might have linear complexity: If the buckets are implemented as singly linked list (as is typical), and all elements have the same key (or the keys happen to have the same hash value) and the erased element happens to be the last in the bucket, then the entire container would need to be traversed.

The constant average assumes an even distribution of keys and a good hash function.

---

However, erasure invalidates the iterator, so behaviour of directing through it after erasure is undefined.

Comment: *"I don't care which element is removed."* But maybe some position are better than other.

Comment: @Jarod42 maybe... you'd have to know something special about the internal structure of the container though. No such special knowledge is mentioned in the question.

Comment: @eerorika I just would like to have the best case complexity scenario. I am not sure about the inner workings of `unordered_set` but can I assume that this is almost constant time?

Comment: @Morpheus worst case is linear; but average is constant as quoted by lubgr.